# OpenVG on wince: nothing painted on screen (example application Star.exe)

Tags: qt, windows-ce, openvg

Has anyone got the openvg example (star.exe) running on a wince target successfully? I’ve tried it but failed – nothing was painted on screen except for an empty window. Below is what I’ve done for it.

Environment:

- Qt 4.7.4
- Wince 6.0
- An SDK with both OpenGL and OpenVG support. (OpenVG version 1.1)

Steps:

1. Open "Visual Studio 2005 Command Prompt", configure Qt with command:

   ```
   configure -openvg -platform win32-msvc2005 -xplatform wince60DbAu1300-qt46-mipsii-msvc2005
   ```
2. Set environment variables for wince.
3. Run "nmake"
4. Copy files needed to the same folder on my target. Below is the file tree in the folder:

   - star.exe
   - QtCored4.dll
   - QtGuid4.dll
   - QtOpenVGd4.dll
   - msvcr80d.dll
5. Run

   ```
   star.exe -graphicssystem OpenVG
   ```

Results:

The window is created and shown, but nothing in it. The content is empty and transparent.

Update:

I was trying to debug this issue, and I found that the application Star.exe is failing to load OPenVG libs.
How do I find out the reason why the app is not able to load OpenVG libs?

Comment: Why don't you try to use Silverlight for Embedded? Is good framework and is on top of OpenGL too.

Answer (score 0):

solution:-

Could figure out the problem. My application was not able to find the graphics libs which are loaded at run time.

the graphics libs has to be in "graphicssystems" folder in star app folder, and the graphics libs can be copied from "QTROOT\plugins\graphicssystems\" folder.

And might have to specify command line arguments "-graphicssystems OpenVG" while launching the application.